# How to get Wiremock to give a default response if template response file not found

Tags: templates, wiremock

I'm currently running Wiremock standalone, and I am trying to mimic a service that accessing a database.

My mapping file looks something like this:-

```json
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPath": "/testService/search/details"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/hal+json"
        },
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "bodyFileName": "/testTable/{{request.query.productCode}}.json" 
    }
}
```

So if I were to hit this url:-
http://localhost/testService/search/details?productCode=12345

Then it will go to the database get return me product 12345.

If I send the service a request that doesn't exist in the database (e.g. productCode=0), it would give me a standard empty response, e.g.:-

```json
{
    "products": []
}
```

I am therefore trying to get wiremock to do the same using the JSON config.

At the minute, if I send wiremock a request with a productCode that doesn't have a corresponding response file, I get this error:-

```
Error 500 java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

But I want it to reply back with an empty response if it doesn't find the response file, so I want to look for a matching response file, if it doesn't find one, then fall back to a default response file, that will have the contents:-

```json
{
    "products": []
}
```

I've can't see anything in the wiremock documentation that refers to a default response on FileNotFoundExcpetion.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you'll need to write a custom response transformer to accomplish this. It would be something like follows:

```java
public static class ExampleTransformer extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer {

        @Override
        public ResponseDefinition transform(Request request, ResponseDefinition responseDefinition, FileSource files, Parameters parameters) {
            String productCode = request.queryParameter("productCode").toString();
            File jsonFile = new File("/path/to/json/testTable/" + productCode + ".json")
            if (jsonFile.exists()) {
                 return responseDefinition;
            } else {
                 return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                    .like(responseDefinition)
                    .but()
                    .withBodyFile("/path/to/empty/product/array/file.json")
                    .build();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "example";
        }
    }
```

You'd then only need to update your existing mapping's transformer to the name you define in `getName()`, and add an empty product JSON file. The transformer will either return the existing defined response with the corresponding product code JSON file or if the file does not exist, it will return the specified empty product JSON file.

(I didn't check for certain that the Java code will compile/run, but this should be more than enough to get you on your way :) )

Comment: Would this work? My original mapping is triggering, as the request matches the mapping, i just don't have the respective template file. I don't think wiremock will execute subsequent mappings after the first one is triggered?
I'm happy to be corrected though!

Comment: I don't think I follow. If you execute the same request twice, you'd get the same response twice. This would work if you had a mapping for `/test`, but didn't have one for `/test2`. The call to `/test` would get the response specified in the mapping file, and the call to `/test2` would get the response specified in this generic.

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully make it easier to understand. The request will remain the same, its just the parameters that differ. If the response file is not there then use a default response. The request portion of my mapping will match the request in all scenarios, whether there is a response file or not.

Comment: Ah! I get your question now -- I'll update my answer with a new solution shortly.

Comment: Updated! Lemme know if I haven't answered your question :D